# Cartan–Remmert reduction of an algebraic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, projective-varieties, stein-manifolds

Let $V$ be a normal connected algebraic (say, quasi-projective) variety over complex numbers. Assume that underlying complex analytic space $V^\text{an}$ is holomorphically convex, and thus admits the *Cartan–Remmert reduction* $\zeta \colon V^{an} \to S$, where $S$ is a Stein manifold. My question is the following: is it true that this reduction in some reasonable sense algebraic, say, there exists a structure of an algebraic variety (or rather algebraic space) on $S$, such that $\zeta$ is an analytification of an algebraic morphism?

Here are some clues why this statement could be true:

1. The Cartan–Remmert reduction is in fact a factorisation modulo equivalence relation “$x \sim y$ iff there exists a connected compact analytic subvariety passing through both $x$ and $y$.” In our case, one can define *algebraic Cartan–Remmert reduction* $R \subseteq V \times V$ as “$(x,y) \in R$ iff there exists a connected proper subvariety passing through both $x$ and $y$.” Then, by GAGA its analytification $R^\text{an}$ should be the Cartan–Remmert equivalence relation on $V^\text{an}$ and $V^\text{an}/R^\text{an}=(V/R)^\text{an}$. The problem is that it is not clear to me whether such a relation exists in the algebraic category, and even less clear whether the quotient exists.
2. In many cases the Cartan–Remmert reduction of a quasi-projective variety can be described explicitly in terms of the boundary divisor. Namely, assume that $X$ is smooth a projective variety, $D \subset X$ an snc-divisor and $U:=X \setminus D$. Assume that the map $\phi_{\lvert D\rvert}$ defined by the linear system $\lvert D\rvert$ is regular and $h^{0}(X,\mathcal{O}(D)) >1$. Then I think I am able to prove that the Stein factorisation of the restriction of $\phi_{\lvert D\rvert}$ on $U$ is the Cartan–Remmert reduction of $U$. In particular, it is an algebraic morphism to an affine variety.
   Unfortunately, this construction does not work in general, it breaks for Serre's examples of non-affine algebraic varieties which are Stein. These examples do not give a counterexample for my initial question because in their case the Cartan–Remmert reduction is just the identity.

UPD.:I was pointed out, that it is not true that the analytification of an arbitrary algebraic variety is Stein. In the case I am interested in this is automatically true, so one can think that this is a part of the assumption.

Comment: I've never heard of the Cartan-Remmert reduction before but point 1 makes it sound like this should be the affinization of $V$ defined as the Spec of the ring of global functions with it's natural map from $V$.

Comment: Should $\zeta$ be $V^\text{an} \to S$, or really $\zeta : V \to S$?

Comment: Take $X$ quasi-affine, with $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ non-Noetherian. What should the Cartan-Remmert reduction of $X_{\rm an}$ be in this case?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger can that happen for $X$ normal? I think the standard example is non-normal.

Comment: @DoriBejleri No, this is exactly what Serre's examples are about. Serre constructed examples of quasi-projective varieties that are Stein, but they admit no non-constant algebraic functions. See Hartshorne' ''Ample subvarieties of algebraic varieties'', Ch. VI Ex. 3.2. If you are a little bit familiar with non-abelian Hodge theory, Serre's examples are de Rham moduli spaces of elliptic curves, that give exotic algebraic structures on the Betti moduli space $(\mathbb{C}^{\times})^{2r}$.

Comment: @V.Rogov Nice, thanks! I was familiar with the example but missed that it had no non-constsnt global functions.